# How can I add two cells in a same table row?

Tags: swift3

I'm very new to swift. I have a table where there are 'n' number of cells. For few selected rows I need to display 2 cells with a dropdown so that each cell can be selected separately.

I tried creating 2 separate views and adding cells but when i click on one cell, complete row is selected. Could anyone please give me idea like how can I continue with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set up n sections for the tableView if you had n cells before and set the `numberOfRowsInSection` to 1 or 2 depending on whether you want a dropdown in that specific section or not.

Something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if shouldHaveDropdown[section] {
        return 2
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return n
}
```

`shouldHaveDropdown` can also be an array of bools with `n` elements, where each element represent whether the section should have a dropdown or not.

Comment: Check my updated code, if you use an array, you obviously need to access an element of the array. Why would you need a loop inside numberOfRowsInSection? That function only returns an `Int`.